# Schematron validating multiple elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, schematron

Assume I have an XML document defining:

```
<people>

  <person>
    <city>London</city>
  </person>
  <person>
    <city>Paris</city>
  </person>

</people>
```

I want a schematron that check that each person lives in London.

I tried:

```
<sch:rule context="people">
            <sch:assert test="person/city = 'London'">Everybody must live in London!</sch:assert>
 </sch:rule>
```

However, this will return true so long as there exists one person that lives in London. Is there a way I can tell schematron to apply a test to each element matching the XPathcondition person/city ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about "no one may live outside London":

```
<sch:rule context="people">
    <sch:assert test="not(person[city != 'London'])">Everybody must live in London!</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

Comment: That looks like it works, thanks. However, is there a way to tell Schematron to apply a condition to all matching elements?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to make assertions for `person` elements, don't make them in the `people` context. (Unless of course you want them to apply only to persons inside of a `<people>` element, in which case you can set the context to `people/person` and the assert to `city = 'London'`.)

Answer (score 3):

This has many different solutions. Example solution 1, report if someone is not living in London:

```
<sch:rule context="people">
  <sch:report test="person/city != 'London'">Everybody must live in London!</sch:report>
</sch:rule>
```

Example solution 2, asserts that every single person must be living in London, note that this reports every person not living in London as an error instead of only reporting the node `people`.

```
<sch:rule context="people/person">
    <sch:assert test="city = 'London'">This person should be living in london</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```